# Can we create Deep Link to Android apps which has no host (Domain) registered in Android Manifest.xml?

Tags: android, deep-linking, deeplink, attribution, utm-tracking

Let's assume the package name of application is com.example.com with below entry in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity ...>
    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="http"/>
        <data android:scheme="https"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The app doesn't have / own any domain, there is no mapping of application package to domain in assetlinks.json as given by Android developer documentation
https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html

E.g.: 
https://www.example.net/.well-known/assetlinks.json

Can we define & achieve Deep Link using URLs schemas below:

market://details?id=com.example.com OR
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.com

Secondly, In the application we have below Intent Filter to track UTM Parameters

```
   <receiver
      android:name=".main.activity.InstallTrackersReceiver"
      android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

How do we ensure the app is deep Linked &  we are able to get UTM parameters even when they are set in market:// http:// schema Deep Link URLs like below:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.example.com&utm_source=web

Any guidance or suggestion would be very helpful.